# Why am I still unable to run a script on NTFS partitions after remount with suitable perssimions?

Tags: permissions, mount, scripts, filesystem, executable

I use a mobile hard disk in ubuntu and I want to run scripts on the disk.
At first, the permission is denied. Therefore, I followed the advices in this answer [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)
and use

`sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000,uid=scw4750,gid=scw4750 /dev/sdf1 /media/Elements`

to remount the disk.

After this the permission becomes:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 scw4750 scw4750 32  6月  1 14:45 test.sh*
```

However, when I run test.sh with >>./test.sh

It returns:

```
bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied
```

Why do this happens? How to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: You can run any bash script (executable or not) with `bash scriptname.sh`

Comment: Thanks @BharadwajRaju, I tried and it works. But how can I run with ./test.sh?

Comment: That will have to be answered by someone else, but it looks like you are with `rw` permissions, only read-write — not execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the `mount` manpage, the `user` mount option implicitly turns on the `noexec` option as well

```
user   Allow an ordinary user to mount the filesystem.  The name of the
       mounting user is written to mtab so  that  he  can  unmount  the
       filesystem  again.   This  option  implies  the  options noexec,
       nosuid, and nodev (unless overridden by subsequent  options,  as
       in the option line user,exec,dev,suid).
```

where

```
noexec Do  not  allow  direct  execution of any binaries on the mounted
       filesystem.
```

Comment: Then what should I do? @steeldriver

Comment: Like the manpage says, either remove the `user` option from your mount command or add an explicit `exec` option AFTER the `user` option. Since you're mounting using `sudo`, the first solution probably makes most sense.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer doesn't appear in the search for `noexec` related issues and this site has had two related questions that I have seen in the past few days ... Probably it should be upvoted more.