# Secondary partition -I cant Execute files

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, fstab

I have set up my /etc/fstab like this:

```
UUID=7817297e-3368-45aa-85b8-5bcbf23c1698 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=980f8f6f-1aec-4a7c-b6a3-1037311f7c36 /media/m/DataLinux               ext4    errors=remount-ro,auto,exec,rw,user 0       2
UUID=1C84-969B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

On the partition "DataLinux" I can't execute .sh and appimages(with execution on)

How do I fix it?

Comment: IIRC `user` implies `noexec` - see related [Why am I still unable to run a script on NTFS partitions after remount with suitable perssimions?](https://askubuntu.com/a/780275/178692)

Comment: It works - THANK!



I placed the user, before the exec



UUID=980f8f6f-1aec-4a7c-b6a3-1037311f7c36 /media/m/DataLinux               ext4    errors=remount-ro,auto,user,exec,rw 0       2