# Permission denied when running script, but correct file permissions and ownership are in place

Tags: bash, permissions, fstab, mountpoint, ownership

I am unable to run scripts that I previously had been doing:

```
$ SCRIPT.SH
bash: /media/USER/PATH/bin/SCRIPT.SH: Permission denied
```

Checking the file permissions and ownership, that are as expected:

```
$ ll PATH/bin
total 1
-rwxr--r-- 1 USER USER 1425 Aug  5 09:23 SCRIPT.SH
```

I have also tried running the scripts with `sudo`, and even given a test script full permissions:

```
chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx SCRIPT.SH
```

Everything leads to the same `bash: Permission denied` message

**Background:**
The scripts are located on a USB HDD, as they were when they could be run.
What has changed is: the drive label,
The updated `.bashrc` PATH entry for the 'new location'
`PATH="/media/USER/MOUNTDIRECTORY/bin:$PATH"`

And so the volume was mounted at the same 'named' place, an fstab entry
`UUID=UUID /media/USER/MOUNTDIRECTORY ext4    defaults,user,auto  0   1`

I'm clearly missing something!

Comment: Unmount that filesystem and remove the mount option `user` as it implies `noexec` which will prevent binary executable e.g. `/bin/bash` from running on that virtual filesystem mount ... Then, mount it again and it should work..

Comment: or alternatively, add the `exec` option after `user` like `defaults,user,exec,auto`

Comment: ... see for example [Why am I still unable to run a script on NTFS partitions after remount with suitable perssimions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780233/why-am-i-still-unable-to-run-a-script-on-ntfs-partitions-after-remount-with-suit)

Comment: @Raffa, thank you so much, that seems to have worked nicely. A valuable lesson there, I knew I should have dug deeper into the fstab settings!